# GitHub Actions Checkout submodules doesn't work

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I do have a private organisation repository. Let's call it **my_private_repo**.
Inside this repository I do have a clone of a public repository from outside of organisation. Let's call it **my_public_repo**.

In my repository I do have the .gitmodules file:

```
[submodule "path_to_my_public_repo"]
    path = path_to_my_public_repo       
    url = git://path_to_my_public_repo
```

When I run the `git submodule status` command, the submodule appears.

In the YAML file I want to checkout the code and I use this scrtip:

```
name: practice
on:
     push:
         branches:
             - github-action-practice
     workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
     get-code:
         runs-on: ubuntu-latest
         steps:
             - name: Checkout
               uses: actions/checkout@v3
               with:
                 submodules: recursive
```

When I try to run the workflow I encounter this message:

`No url found for submodule path 'path_to_my_public_repo' in .gitmodules`

`The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128`

I search for similar problems and I tried several solutions, none worked.

For example I generated a token from my organisational account and add it to secrets and put it inside the checkout action. It didn't work.

```
jobs:
     get-code:
         runs-on: ubuntu-latest
         steps:
             - name: Checkout
               uses: actions/checkout@v3
               with:
                 submodules: recursive
                 token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

I also tried to run the git command for update submodule. Same result.

```
jobs:
     get-code:
         runs-on: ubuntu-latest
         steps:
             - name: Checkout
               uses: actions/checkout@v3
             - name: Get submodule
               run: git submodule update --init --recursive
```

If you know or have any idea on what else I can try, please let me know

Comment: Is the URL in .gitmodules a Github URL? I believe the first party action only supports github repos

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set `fetch-depth: 0`, like:

```
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          submodules: recursive
```

In case of **private repo**, you should also need to configure git to access private modules/repos, like:

```
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          submodules: recursive
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_API_TOKEN }}

      - name: Configure git for private modules
        env:
          GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_API_TOKEN }}
        run: git config --global url."https://x:${GITHUB_API_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
```

Comment: Hello, I updated the text of the problem by specifying that the public repository is outside of the organisation. Maybe this changes the problem a little bit. Unfortunately adding `fetch-dept: 0` doesn't help. The error remains the same